# How to use Neural network for non binary input and output

Tags: matlab

I tried to use the modified version of NN  back propagation code by Phil Brierley
(www.philbrierley.com). When i try to solve the XOR problem it works perfectly. but when i try to solve a problem of the form output = x1^2 + x2^2  (ouput = sum of squares of input), the results are not accurate. i have scaled the input and ouput between -1 and 1. I get different results every time i run the same program (i understand its due to random wts initialization), but results are very different. i tried changing learning rate but still results converge.

have given the code below

```
%---------------------------------------------------------
% MATLAB neural network backprop code
% by Phil Brierley
%--------------------------------------------------------
clear; clc; close all;


%user specified values
hidden_neurons = 4;
epochs = 20000;

input = [];
for i =-10:2.5:10
for j = -10:2.5:10
input = [input;i j];
end
end

output  = (input(:,1).^2 + input(:,2).^2);
output1 = output;

% Maximum input and output limit and scaling factors
m1  = -10;   m2  = 10;
m3  = 0;     m4  = 250;
c = -1;      d   = 1;

%Scale input and output
for i =1:size(input,2)
I   = input(:,i);
scaledI = ((d-c)*(I-m1) ./ (m2-m1)) + c;
input(:,i) = scaledI;
end
for i =1:size(output,2)
I   = output(:,i);
scaledI = ((d-c)*(I-m3) ./ (m4-m3)) + c;
output(:,i) = scaledI;
end

train_inp = input;
train_out = output;

%read how many patterns and add bias
patterns  = size(train_inp,1);
train_inp = [train_inp ones(patterns,1)];

%read how many inputs and initialize learning rate
inputs = size(train_inp,2);
hlr    = 0.1;

%set initial random weights
weight_input_hidden = (randn(inputs,hidden_neurons) - 0.5)/10;
weight_hidden_output = (randn(1,hidden_neurons) - 0.5)/10;

%Training
err = zeros(1,epochs);

for iter = 1:epochs

alr = hlr;
blr = alr / 10;

%loop through the patterns, selecting randomly
for j = 1:patterns

%select a random pattern
patnum = round((rand * patterns) + 0.5);
if patnum > patterns
patnum = patterns;
elseif patnum < 1
patnum = 1;    
end

%set the current pattern
this_pat = train_inp(patnum,:);
act = train_out(patnum,1);

%calculate the current error for this pattern
hval = (tanh(this_pat*weight_input_hidden))';
pred = hval'*weight_hidden_output';
error = pred - act;

% adjust weight hidden - output
delta_HO = error.*blr .*hval;
weight_hidden_output = weight_hidden_output - delta_HO';

% adjust the weights input - hidden
delta_IH= alr.*error.*weight_hidden_output'.*(1-(hval.^2))*this_pat;
weight_input_hidden = weight_input_hidden - delta_IH';

end
% -- another epoch finished

%compute overall network error at end of each epoch
pred      = weight_hidden_output*tanh(train_inp*weight_input_hidden)';
error     = pred' - train_out;
err(iter) =  ((sum(error.^2))^0.5);

%stop if error is small
if err(iter) < 0.001
fprintf('converged at epoch: %d\n',iter);
break 
end

end

%Output after training
pred  = weight_hidden_output*tanh(train_inp*weight_input_hidden)';
Y     = m3 + (m4-m3)*(pred-c)./(d-c);

% Testing for a new set of input
input_test  = [6 -3.1; 0.5 1; -2 3; 3 -2; -4 5; 0.5 4; 6 1.5];
output_test = (input_test(:,1).^2 + input_test(:,2).^2);
input1      = input_test;

%Scale input
for i =1:size(input1,2)
I   = input1(:,i);
scaledI = ((d-c)*(I-m1) ./ (m2-m1)) + c;
input1(:,i) = scaledI;
end

%Predict output
train_inp1 = input1;
patterns   = size(train_inp1,1);
bias       = ones(patterns,1);
train_inp1 = [train_inp1 bias];
pred1      = weight_hidden_output*tanh(train_inp1*weight_input_hidden)';

%Rescale
Y1  = m3 + (m4-m3)*(pred1-c)./(d-c);

analy_numer = [output_test Y1']
plot(err)
```

This is the sample output i get for problem

state after 20000 epochs

```
analy_numer =

45.6100   46.3174
1.2500   -2.9457
13.0000   11.9958
13.0000    9.7097
41.0000   44.9447
16.2500   17.1100
38.2500   43.9815
```

if i run once more i get different results. as can be observed for small values of input i get totally wrong ans (negative ans not possible). for other values accuracy is still poor.

can someone tell what i am doing wrong and how to correct.

thanks
raman

Comment: This is a huge piece of code to dig through (and I bet lots of it is not even relevant). Please step through your code a bit to find the problem area (where results are starting to be different than you expected). From there we can help you much more efficiently.

Comment: Thank for the response. I have just modified the code remove irrelevant portions (corresponding to XOR problem). The implementation of the algorithm is correct, and the results are logically correct. I just want to know how to improve the results. i have tried to play with the number of input neurons, the learning but rate, but results dont improve significantly. My question is: Is this the best possible results that can be obtained for non-binary inputs using a backpropation network, if not what can be done to improve its accuracy. I have edited the previously posted code.